# missing com.android.nfc.cardemulation.HostEmulationManager in android.jar

Tags: android, debugging, hce

I want to debug my HostCardEmulation App in eclipse. To see which select AID command is send from the reader, I want to step into Android source code: but I can't find com.android.nfc.cardemulation.HostEmulationManager.java (class) in android.jar.

Answer (score 0):

This class is not part of the Android framework (i.e. the classes that comprise the Android API). Instead it is part of the Android NFC system service (the system component that manages the NFC stack). The NFC service and your apps (through the framework classes) communicate through IPC techniques. Hence, there is no need (from an SDK perspective) to have the source code of such system services.

Consequently, this class is not "missing" but it is simply not supposed to be part of the Android SDK (android.jar) as the SDK only contains the framework classes (i.e. the classes that *your* apps can be compiled against). You can still get its source code from the AOSP project: [packages/apps/Nfc](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Nfc/).